# Pervasive SQL with WHERE - matching spaces

Tags: php, sql, regex, pervasive

Our accounting application is using Pervasive SQL 10. I need to fetch data of products from it. Problem is that the "name" column has fixed length of 12 and the application is filling the rest with spaces.

So every time I use my PHP script to fetch data, I need to fill the rest of the name with spaces to match it in `WHERE` clause.

**Example data in the column:**

- 65LD11
- 42BRD03
- 65LD112
- (space)65LD12
- 165LD12

I have been using: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '65LD12%';`. Which is not perfect, but the biggest problem is with the name with space as first character, because I can't use `_` or `%` as it would match both 65LD12 and 165LD12 name.

There can be any number of spaces at the beginning or at the end. In MySQL I would use `REGEXP_LIKE` to match only the spaces, but here in Pervasive I am kind of lost. Is there some way how to do this?

Comment: I can understand space padding at the end (up to a point, anyway) but space prefixing is just plain odd. Can you fix up the data? Why is the item with a space prefix like that?

Comment: Well, actually its the problem with the app, I was making an example to make it simple, but why this is happening is that in DB there are two columns (name1 - 12chars, name2 - 5chars), if you put in the name, which is longer then 12 chars, its split and the rest is saved to name2 column, so if the space is 13th char its the first one in name2, so unfortunately I can't fix it.

Comment: Righto. I now understand why it happens, though I don't quite follow why it cannot be fixed. Sounds like something that needs a bit more logic at `INSERT` time?

Comment: Right, I dont like that app, unfortunately I dont have access to source code, so I can't fix it, I only have access to DB, so I just have to deal with it.. This is not the only problem with that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Pervasive, but in Standard SQL you can do a simple

```
WHERE TRIM(name) = '65LD12'
```

Of course it would be better to clean the data and remove unnecessary leading spaces, TRIM will prevent the usage on an index. And then *name = '65LD12'* should return the correct data regardless of trailing blanks (again, I don't know if Pervasive implements that correctly)

**edit based on comments:**

There's no TRIM in Pervasive, but LTRIM:

```
WHERE LTRIM(name) = '65LD12'
```

If this is still not returning the correct rows (i.e. Pervasive implemented string comparison in a wrong way) you have to add RTRIM, too:

```
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(name)) = '65LD12'
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, unfortunatelly Pervasive says that it doesn't know TRIM. The reason why there are spaces I explained in the comment of my question.

Comment: A DBMS without a TRIM function? Maybe there's *LTRIM/RTRIM*, which is the same as *TRIM(LEADING/TRAILING FROM name)*. If you want to *TRIM(BOTH FROM name)* you might have to nest it: *LTRIM(RTRIM(name))*

Comment: PervasiveSQL v10 and v11 know `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` string functions: [v10](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv10/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/scalarfunc.6.2.html) and [v11](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=ODBC/scalarfunc.05.2.html) documentation.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for editing it, Im gonna mark this as an answer as this is better solution than the REPLACE, which would also replace the spaces in the middle of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE REPLACE(name,' ','') LIKE '65LD12%';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to solve the problem. I completely forgot about REPLACE function :)

Comment: @InToSSH: could you swap the `LIKE` for an `=` here? Might offer a bit more performance.

Comment: @halfer : sure, thanks for suggestion, however I will have to use LTRIM and RTRIM, as I found out that there are some names with spaces in the middle, which would be replaced aswell if I used this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Replace function. http://help.pervasive.com/display/DI1025/StrReplace+Function

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunatelly this function is not for SQL but Data Integrator.